# Python Basic Slot Machine not Running?

Tags: python, class

So I spent the past day or so working on this slot machine program for a school assignment, and for some reason the only thing that will happen when I run the program is it will print the first statement in the function but then close the script.

```py
import random

STATS = {"Win": 0, "Lose": 0}

def playSlots():
    player = Player("Player")
    game = Game(player, [])
    print("Welcome to my not as rough slot machine, now featuring classes!")
    gaw = SlotMachine(1,1,1)
    SlotMachine.playRound
    if player.money < 1:
        print("Out of Money")



class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.money = 10

    def getMoney(self):
        return self.money

    def changeMoney(self, value):
        self.credits += value

class Game:
    def __init__(self, player, stats):
        self.player = player
        self.stats = stats

    def statChange(self, outcome):
        global STATS
        if outcome == "Win":
            STATS["Win"] += 1
        elif outcome == "Lose":
            STATS["Lose"] += 1

class SlotMachine:

    def __init__(self, slotL, slotC, slotR):
        self.slotL = 1
        self.slotC = 1
        self.slotR = 1

    def randomSlots(self):
        self.slotL = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        self.slotC = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        self.slotR = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        return self.slotL, self.slotC, self.slotR

    def playRound(self):
        while Player.getMoney > 1:
            print("You have",Player.getMoney(), "tokens")
            playerWager = int(input("Enter the amount of money you would like to wager: "))
            if playerWager > Player.getMoney() or playerWager == 0:
                print("Invalid Wager")
                continue
            Player.changeMoney(playerWager)
            self.randomSlots
            print(self.slotL, "|", self.slotC, "|", self.slotR)
            if (self.slotL == self.slotC) and (self.slotC == self.slotR):
                print("Win")
                Player.changeMoney((playerWager * 2))
                Game.statChange("Win")
                print("Money: ", Player.getMoney())
            else:
                print("Lose")
                Game.statChange("Lose")
                print("Money: ", Player.getMoney())
                if Player.getMoney() < 1:
                    print("Out of Money")
                    break
            userContinue = input("Continue? (q to quit): ")
            if userContinue == "q":
                break

def main():
    playSlots()
main()
```

I'm kind of at a loss at this point, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try `SlotMachine.playRound()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python  method or a function call syntax is

### method calls

```
[instance.]instance_method<left parenthesis> [<arguments>]><right parenthesis>
```

Verbally this means, syntax for calling method or a function in python is:- first optionally specify the variable of instance object( or class name for static method) followed by dot(.) operator. For functions this steps do not required. Then method name,  followed by left parenthesis and right parenthesis. optionally arguments for the method are specified in between the parenthesis.
On the following line it seems that you want to call method, but actually you didn't.

```
SlotMachine.playRound
```

This does not invoke method calling. But simply returns an object of instancemethod type.
Since playRound is instance method conventional way to call the method is using instance object.e.g gaw object like:

```
gaw.playRound()
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

when you creating instance for class, you should call the function using that instance only. 
the changes I made i ur code is `gaw.playRound(player,game)` and `def playRound(self,player,game):` inside playRound function we have to use player and game instances only for that particular player. **The below code is working for me. Once try this.**

```
import random

STATS = {"Win": 0, "Lose": 0}

def playSlots():
    player = Player("Player")
    game = Game(player, [])
    print("Welcome to my not as rough slot machine, now featuring classes!")
    gaw = SlotMachine(1,1,1)
    gaw.playRound(player,game)
    if player.money < 1:
        print("Out of Money")



class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.money = 10
        self.credits = 0

    def getMoney(self):
        return self.money

    def changeMoney(self, value):
        self.credits += value

class Game:
    def __init__(self, player, stats):
        self.player = player
        self.stats = stats

    def statChange(self, outcome):
        global STATS
        if outcome == "Win":
            STATS["Win"] += 1
        elif outcome == "Lose":
            STATS["Lose"] += 1

class SlotMachine:

    def __init__(self, slotL, slotC, slotR):
        self.slotL = 1
        self.slotC = 1
        self.slotR = 1

    def randomSlots(self):
        self.slotL = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        self.slotC = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        self.slotR = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        return self.slotL, self.slotC, self.slotR

    def playRound(self,player,game):
        while player.getMoney() > 1:
            print("You have",player.getMoney(), "tokens")
            playerWager = int(input("Enter the amount of money you would like to wager: "))
            if playerWager > player.getMoney() or playerWager == 0:
                print("Invalid Wager")
                continue
            player.changeMoney(playerWager)
            self.randomSlots
            print(self.slotL, "|", self.slotC, "|", self.slotR)
            if (self.slotL == self.slotC) and (self.slotC == self.slotR):
                print("Win")
                player.changeMoney((playerWager * 2))
                game.statChange("Win")
                print("Money: ", player.getMoney())
            else:
                print("Lose")
                game.statChange("Lose")
                print("Money: ", Player.getMoney())
                if player.getMoney() < 1:
                    print("Out of Money")
                    break
            userContinue = input("Continue? (q to quit): ")
            if userContinue == "q":
                break

def main():
    playSlots()
main()
```